# CodeIgniter - Ajax Json call to controller not working

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am current using CodeIgniter 2.2.2
I have the following controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class switchLang extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

                $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function changeLang()
    {
            log_message('debug', 'INSIDE');
            //echo "test";

            $data = array("STATUS"=>"true");
            //echo "HI";
            echo json_encode($data) ;   
    }

    public function index(){
        }   
}
```

And inside my view I have the following ajax call:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {      
                                var base_url = '<?php echo site_url('switchLang/changeLang');?>';

                                $('#lang').click(function(event) {
                                        console.log(5 + 6);
                                        $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    'url' : base_url,
                    'type' : 'POST', 
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'data' : 'data',
                    'success' : function(data){ 
                                console.log(data);
                                 if(data){
                                    location.reload(); 
                                }
                             }
                                    });

                                });
                        });
</script>
```

I am trying to reload page on success ajax call. However I am getting only the following response in my Chrome debugger and nothing happens.

Comment: In your ajax call what value you are getting for ``base_url`` ??

Comment: ``/switchLang/changeLang`` is repeating in above url.  Is it the correct URL ??

Comment: This is what I meant: http://localhost:8080/a1/switchLang/changeLang

Comment: Seems like I always have problem with the url in codeigniter. But in this case, I don't think my url is incorrect. Because I try copy and pasting the url in my browser and it is working perfectly

Comment: is it showing any errors in console log when you make this akax call and also can you try by replacing ``var base_url = '<?php echo site_url('switchLang/changeLang');?>';``  with ``var base_url = "/switchLang/changeLang";``

Comment: No that didn't help as it is not showing any error message

Comment: Seems like whatever I put inside the base_url, it only makes a mock post call and thats it.

Comment: Try with replacing `echo json_encode($data) ;`  with `header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();`

Comment: btw you reloading page after success.So I think you cannot see what is going on.

Comment: Try without reloading as alredy suggested. Since you are not posting anything to controller, for sake of test try with AJAX GET type to see  what will be result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there may be quotation problem change:

`var base_url = '<?php echo site_url('switchLang/changeLang');?>';`

to

`var base_url = '<?php echo site_url("switchLang/changeLang");?>';`

Comment: What is the difference between those two lines? j

Comment: what is shown in console log by type `console.log(data);` ?